# Asynch problem when fetching MySQL and EXPRESS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, object

I'm trying to simple add a new property in an object. The array of objs is being fetched from my database and then I try to add a property which is also fetched from my database. Although when I try to manipulate it I'm receiving "undefined".

- Is it indeed an asynch problem?
- Am I doing any silly mistakes?

Those are questions that surrounds my head at the moment.

Code:

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {

    Report.fetchAll().then(([rows, fieldData]) => {

        // console.log(rows);
        const modifiedRows = rows.map(el => {

            Report.fetchUserNameOfReport(el.UserInfo_idPessoa).then(([rows, fieldData]) => {
                console.log(rows);
                return {
                    ...el,
                    userOfReport: 'Joao' //change later to smthing like rows.name
                };
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            // return{
            //     ...el,
            //     userOfReport: 'Joao'
            // };

        });

        res.render('user/index', { reports: rows, pageTitle: 'Social Reporter', path: '/' });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

};
```

Obs This works if comment this out and comment Report.fetchUserNameOfReport function->

```
        // return{
        //     ...el,
        //     userOfReport: 'Joao'
        // };
```

Expected result:

```
  {
    idComplaint: 83059,
    title: '4444',
    description: '4444',
    image: '4444',
    location: '4444',
    UserInfo_idPessoa: 80068,
    userOfReport: 'Joao'
  }
```

Actual result:

```
undefined
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never return anything in your `.map`, so all of the values of `modifiedRows` will be `undefined`. You can map them all to promises to get all the values, and then access the modified rows once you wait for all of the promises to resolve. Also, you're shadowing your variable by declaring `rows` and `fieldData` multiple times:

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {

    Report.fetchAll().then(([rows, fieldData]) => {

        // console.log(rows);
        const modifiedRowPromises = rows.map(el => {
            return Report.fetchUserNameOfReport(el.UserInfo_idPessoa).then(([rows2, fieldData2]) => {
                console.log(rows2);
                return {
                    ...el,
                    userOfReport: 'Joao' //change later to smthing like rows2.name
                };
            });
        });

        Promise.all(modifiedRowPromises).then(modifiedRows => {
            res.render('user/index', { reports: modifiedRows, pageTitle: 'Social Reporter', path: '/' });
        }).catch(console.log);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Alternatively, if you use `async/await` syntax, this can be achieved much more cleanly:

```
exports.getIndex = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const [rows, fieldData] = Report.fetchAll();

        const modifiedRowPromises = rows.map(async el => {
            const [rows2, fieldData2] = await Report.fetchUserNameOfReport(el.UserInfo_idPessoa);
            return {
                ...el,
                userOfReport: 'Joao' //change later to smthing like rows2.name
            };
         });

         const modifiedRows = await Promise.all(modifiedRowPromises);
         res.render('user/index', { reports: modifiedRows, pageTitle: 'Social Reporter', path: '/' };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: really quick response mate. Works perfectly. I will try to understand your solution and also have a look at Promise. Thank you so much

Comment: @Guibrother32 no problem, and yeah read up a bit about asynchronous code in JavaScript and you'll understand why this had to be done like this

Comment: @Guibrother32 by the way, when you did things like `Report.fetchAll().then(...`, you were already using promises